# Angularjs service response

Tags: angularjs

I am using angularjs to call server method and getting return response. But the problem is that response from the angularjs service is empty to the controller. Consider my code:

```
testModule.factory('testService', ['$http', function ($http){

    return {
        getResponse: getResponse
    };

    function getResponse(url, data)
    {

        var returnResponse = {};

        $http({

            'url' : url,
            'method' : 'POST',
            'data' : data
        })
        .success(function(response){

            returnResponse = response;
            console.log(returnResponse);  <-- here it prints the object with data inside.
        });

        console.log(returnResponse);  <-- here it prints empty value for returnResponse.

        return returnResponse;
    }
}]);
```

as describe in the code the problem is that outside of success function object get null or empty value. Please suggest something.
Thanks.

Comment: check response headers of the HTTP request. 99% chances that you have a cross-domain security fail like 99% of new angulars developers that do a WS call.

Answer (score 1):

This is because the request that `http` request that you are calling , is an asynchronous call.

You could think like a different thread going and executing that function and the rest of the function would resume executing normally.

So,
as soon as you hit $http(..)

```
|  .
v  .
|  $http(....)   -----> I would go and get it evaluated asynchronously
V                        When I finish, I will execute anything that lies in success 
|                          callback
v  console.log(...); ------> I will not wait for success to call, that is an async 
|                              operation I will print the value of returnResponse just 
v                                after I hit $http(...), I won't wait for its response
```

Thus, your console.log(), which is outside the success callback, `returnResponse`, does not have anything and thus prints undefined or null.

The important concept that you could use here is of Promises or Q. Browse it through. That should be a safe resort to your problem here.

Hope you understood.